# enter name ,grade then print name and classified grade

Tags: java, switch-statement

I was given the following problem:

Write a Java program that prompts the user to enter names of 10 students
    and their grades as one string separated with ‘,’. For each student, print out
    his name and classified grade. 
    **Note: use for loop and switch. 
    **Hint: A (90-100) , B ( 80-89) , C (70-79) , D ( 60 – 69)

```
     Sample Run:

     Student1: Sara Alhazmi,88
     Output:
     Sara Alhazmi : B

     Student2: Nada Alamri,95
     Output:
    Nada Alamri : A

 (**Repeated 10 times)
```

Below is my solution:"after correcting my mistakes"
thanks for helpe :)

```
  import java.util.*;
   public class students{
   public static void main(String args[])
  { Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        int f = 10;
        for (int i = 1; i <= f; i++)
    { System.out.println("Student" + i + ":");
     String s = input.nextLine();//s=name student and 
     String name = s.substring(0, s.indexOf(","));//name student 
     String sgrade = s.substring(s.indexOf(",")+1);//grad student
    double grade = Double.parseDouble(sgrade) / 10;// I can not use string with loop so I convert to double because I Divided 
      int ingrade = (int)Math.round(grade); // then I convert to integer 
       switch (ingrade) {
        case 10: 
         System.out.println(name + ": A");
        break;
         case 9:
        System.out.println(name + ": A");
            break;
         case 8: 
       System.out.println(name + ": B"); 
         break;
         case 7: 
     System.out.println(name + ": C");
        break;
         case 6:
       System.out.println(name + ": D");
          break; 

   }//end  while loop
  }//end for loop
 }// end main
 }// end class
```

Comment: What is your question, hanooee?

Comment: Your problem is that your switch statement only looks for the distinct values 100, 89, 79, 69. Everything else will get an f (that should be uppercase)

Answer (score 1):

Like @KeepCalmAndCarryOn said, your switch statement needs to include ranges, not just individual numbers.  Think of it in terms of if/else if and that will help you re-define your switch.